# Is there a valid Blokus configuration where all the pieces are on the board?

Tags: blokus

Is there a configuration of Blokus pieces where all pieces of one colour touch only at the corners and not the edges, so that the pieces could actually appear that way in a Blokus game, with each player ending up with a score of 0?

Solutions for both the four-player and two-player game would be appreciated.

Comment: And by a score of 0 I really mean 15, but the way I play with others, we count positive points and aim for a low score.

Comment: [I've done this playing Solitaire. Complete with provable last placement of the single.](http://dampes8n.com/perfect.jpg)

Comment: @DampeS8N Yay for a 4-way rotationally symmetrical solution!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After poking around a while for information on the scoring system, I found this site:

http://puzzlesland.com/blokus/

[image]

It contains an "optimal configuration" as I asked for in the original question, plus various other hypothetical configurations that were figured out.

Comment: I would just like to check, this is not normally possible if all players play strategically and use blocking, am I correct?

Comment: @VortexYT If players are playing strategically there is almost no chance that this will happen, this is the kind of outcome you need to be aiming for in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

Yes! They all can fit, just takes time and careful configuration.

[image: blokus game. All the pieces fit!]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I did! Not so easy! But try! You can find another solution.